# Read DIN (Driver Identification Number) from a smart card (drivercard)

Tags: smartcard, apdu, serial-number

I'd like to know how to get a DIN (Driver Identification Number) from a smartcard. The card is a driver card, used to store tachograph data.

I can already communicate with the smartcard reader but I don't have a clue about how to read that information.

Looking at the smartcard faces, it shows a list of (I think) record numbers:

1. Surname
  2. Given name(s)
  3. Date and place of birth
  ...
  5b. Card Number

The last one is the info I need: Card Number on record 5b.

I'm not experienced with smartcard reading. I don't know what I have to do. I suppose I have to send a "select file" APDU command and then read the 5b record, but don't know which file or how to format that commands.

On the card, there is a rectangle with E1 inside, and 182 under it, don't know if that could be a hint about what to read...

I know driver cards need authentication to read important data but I think the card number is something public (not sure though).

Who can help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you are refering to a tachograph driver card according to the ECC regulation No 3821/85, right?

In that case, the communication flow with the card would be something like the following:

1. SELECT tachograph application

   ```
   00 A4 04 0C 06 FF544143484F
   ```
2. SELECT elementary file by file identifier (`xxxx`)

   ```
   00 A4 02 0C 02 xxxx
   ```
3. READ BINARY to get file data (`zz` bytes from offset `xxyy`)

   ```
   00 B0 xx yy zz
   ```

The card number would typically be in EF Identification (FID `0520`), 16 bytes starting at byte 1.

You can find a complete specification of the driver card's protocol and data structures as part of the regulation document ([here](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CONSLEG:1985R3821:20111001%3aEN%3aPDF)).